# Windows command line history

Tags: windows, command-line, history

is there any place in windows where in admin or super user changes/commands are stored? like how linux has .bash_history for root?

Comment: If you give a little bit more context on what exactly you are trying to achieve, we might be able to point you to the proper source of information.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/290107/bash-history-like-feature-for-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 2):

for 'powershell' i found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/perserving-command-history-across-sessions/) blog entry:

```
$MaximumHistoryCount = 1KB

if (!(Test-Path ~\PowerShell -PathType Container))
{   New-Item ~\PowerShell -ItemType Directory
}

function bye 
{   Get-History -Count 1KB |Export-CSV ~\PowerShell\history.csv
    exit
}

if (Test-path ~\PowerShell\History.csv)
{   Import-CSV ~\PowerShell\History.csv |Add-History
}
```

then you have to end the session with "bye" (instead of "exit" or closing the window via the "x" button).

Comment: no need to do that. PowerShell already saves the history by default

Answer (score 1):

No, the windows Command Prompt **does not have** automatic logging facilities.

And actually, the linux .bash_history is not only for root - it's for any bash user that doesn't explicitely disable it.

Answer (score 1):

the only thing which comes "close" to something like a "stored history" (but only for the current session) is to press <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/stupid-command-prompt-tricks.html

Answer (score 1):

Besides F7, to print the command history of current session, run:

```
DOSKEY /history
```

Comment: In case anyone wants to do this in C, it's using the following undocumented calls: `DWORD GetConsoleCommandHistoryLengthW(LPWSTR ExeName)` and `DWORD GetConsoleCommandHistoryW(LPWSTR Buffer, DWORD BufferLength, LPWSTR ExeName)`.